# Two divs not displaying equally in IE/Chrome, only in Firefox

Tags: css, drupal-6, cross-browser

The website: http://epic.lexcorp.ca/capabilities

If you open it in Firefox and then in Internet Explorer/Chrome you should see what I mean, and this is in regards to the two areas below the content (View Our Projects and News)

I've been trying to figure this out for about 40 minutes now and I'm at a loss. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's that `</br>` doing right before `<h1>News</h1>` ?  Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from BumbleB2na I noticed there was a 
 at the front of one of the  tags.

That helped, but didn't fix it completely. I then noticed that there was `margin-top` areas that were pushing down the boxes entirely, so I adjusted the values to the div wrapping container and changed them to padding.

Seems to be seamless in all 3 browsers now.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a CSS problem.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.bottomBox .region {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I ended up finding a different solution, the 'margin-top' that was pushing the tables down wasn't working efficiently, so I changed that value to a 'padding-top' on the wrapper div surrounding each table.

Thanks though!